# iOS - return value from heightForRowAtIndexPath after block executed

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, block, heightforrowatindexpath

I'm new to iOS development, in my application I need to calculate the height of dynamic table cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

The problem is that I don't want to return value before "callback" block is finished.. is there a way in objective-c to do this?

That's my method implementation:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    ...
    SDImageCache *imageCache = [[SDImageCache alloc] init];
    [imageCache queryDiskCacheForKey:model.thumbnail done:^(UIImage *image, SDImageCacheType cacheType)
     {

         // do calculations with height etc.
         // got an error "incompatible block pointer types sending"
         return value;
     }];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will either have to run your block synchronously (that is, block the main thread until the block's completion) and return it then, or you will need to store the calculated height in a storage and reload the cell. The second option is preferred because you are not blocking the main thread and UI. You could present a loading indicator on a placeholder cell, and once you have all the required information, reload the cell and present it properly. You can specify an animation to make this reload transition smooth for the user.

Comment: thanks, but with what method I can reload the cell, and where to call it?

Comment: You call it on the table view. `[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];`

Comment: as I see ``reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`` calls ``heightForRowAtIndexPath`` for every row instead of just the one that changed..

Comment: You shouldn't worry about how the table view implements its logic. It reloads the row in the most performant way it can. Remember, when a row is reloaded, other rows many need to be shifted. So the table view may need to call your method for other rows. The `height` method should be as fast as possible, with little developer logic in it.

Comment: Because your height code starts a block which eventually calls the height method. See the source of the infinite loop now?

Comment: here is how i call it ``[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];`` inside ``cellForRowAtIndexPath`` when the block is finished

Comment: `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` calls `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` but inside `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` you start a block that calls `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:`.

Comment: Where do you call `queryDiskCacheForKey:`?

Comment: inside ``cellForRowAtIndexPath:``

Comment: That one is also called after `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`. You need to flag if you should call `queryDiskCacheForKey` or not, depending on whether you called it for the specific indexpath.